# How to exlude packages from jar?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I want to create a jar file from my project. This jar file not executable, just for library usage to be used in another java app. However, I do not know which maven plugin or dependency do this job. Please help..

I want only some specific packages in this jar file.. So I have to specify package names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the included `maven-jar-plugin` [as per the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html).

```xml
   <project>
      ...
      <build>
        <plugins>
          ...
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/foo/*</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/bar/*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          ...
        </plugins>
      </build>
      ...
    </project>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jarrod. Also, I have learned without maven compiler plugin this plugin does not work.. :) Thats firstly maven compiler plugin has to be executed, then this plugin has to be

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a maven plugin. Just have

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

and do `mvn clean package`. You should see the jar file in `target/`

Comment: Well you are right. But I want only some specific packages in this jar file.. So I have to specify package names.